# Php upload photo to another server

Tags: php, ftp

I have a problem with php file uploader. 
I've a user procile when every user can set up his photo. The php script which load picture is on the main server and photo library is on another server. I wanna store photos to server number 2 and show these on the profile on main server (with page's files).
I know I should do it with use php ftp_put but how I can connect to second server, send photo and show it on first server?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use curl for example, to send the file to the other server, but it really depends of what kind of server it is. If it's apache/php, just send it thanks to a post request.

Have a look at these links:

[How to send a file to a server using curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021763/how-to-send-a-file-to-a-server-using-curl)

[Sending File with cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677817/sending-file-with-curl)